# how can i save data from multiple screens

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a class called "Person" with this 4 fields: name, telephone, document, photo. In the first screen I have 2 fields: "name" and "telephone". In the second one I have 1 field: "document". In the third one I have 1 field: "photo". I´ve already saved fields "name" and "telephone" in database (table "Person"). I don´t know how i can save the others fields, "document" and "photo", at the same table "Person".

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.id15_home, name='id15_home'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.id15_create, name='id15_create'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/document/$', views.id15_document, name='id15_document'), 
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/photo/$', views.id15_photo, name='id15_photo'),
```

Views.py:

```
def id15_home(request):
    return (render(request, "id15/id-15.html"))

def id15_create(request):
    form = id15Form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)  # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()  # associa o models com o forms
        messages.success(request, "CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "NÃO CADASTRADO")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'id15/cadastro.html', context)

def id15_document(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(pessoafisica, id=id)
    form = id15Form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():  
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()  
        messages.success(request, "SUCESS")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "title": instance.id,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form,
    }
   return render(request, 'id15/documento.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class pessoafisica(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, default='', blank=False)
    telephone= models.CharField('Telefone', max_length=10, default='', blank=False)
    document = models.FileField(null=True, default='', blank=True)
    photo = models.FileField(null=True, default='', blank=True)

    # ----- Tratar url quando passa o "id" de uma tela para outra ----- #
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("id15_documento", kwargs={"id": self.id})
        return "/id15/%s" %(self.id)
```

forms.py:

```
class id15Form(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    telephone = forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = pessoafisica
        fields = ('name',
                  'telephone')
```

id-15.html

```
<h1> hellow</h1>
        <a href= '{% url "id15_create" %}'>
            <p><button>Criar minha ID 15</button></p>
        </a>
```

cadastro.html

```
<form class=" bd-form-3 " action="" name="form-name" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<script>
function caps(element){
    element.value = element.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>

    <input type="text" name='name' id="name" class="bd-form-input" onkeyup="caps(this)">
    {{form.name.errors}}
    <input type="text" name='telephone' id="telephone" class="bd-form-input" onkeyup="caps(this)">
    {{form.telephone.errors}}
```

document.html

```
<html>
       <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <head>`enter code here`
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>documento</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>teste de documento</h1>
            <label>Upload do documento</label></br>
            <input type="file" name='docment.url' id="document" ></br></br>
            {{form.document.error}}

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type = "submit" >
                Cadastrar </button>
        </body>
        </form>
        </html>
```

Comment: You need to give us a minimal code example, and explain what you've researched/tried/don't understand, to get a good answer here. But the short version is that you need to persist the user in some way. For example: (1) Pass the ID from the first screen through the second one (e.g., as a hidden form field) so you know which row to update. (2) Add a way to map sessions to user IDs; the first screen can register the current session with the ID of the partially-created user, and the second can then look up the session's ID. And so on.

Comment: So, i´ve already passed the ID from the first screen throught the second one. This is OK. Now, in the second one i need to upload a document and save in the same record.

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments; the UI for it sucks, and the result isn't readable anyway. More importantly, you question should contain all the information needed to answer it without reading the comments. So you either need to edit the question, or create a new one. Usually it's the former, but in this case, I think you have a whole new problem, so create a new question. And make sure to include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist the user ID (which you can get back from the model for the row you just created).

If you're going to need to map sessions to user IDs, the best solution is probably to register the session with the ID as soon as you store the object; then, on the next page's endpoint, you just look up the ID for the current session. (But then you also need to design something for people who, e.g., abandon registration halfway through and try to come back with another browser.)

If you don't need that, don't build it just for this. Instead, just put the ID in a hidden form field on the second page, so when you get the form back it'll be available.

Either way, now that you have the ID, you can look up the `Person` object by ID.

Comment: yes, a i have de ID in the second page. I only don´t know how to save in this second one page. what I have to put in the views.py 'def id15_document".

Comment: @Patricia As I said in a comment on the question, if you have a new problem, create a new question. And make sure it's an MCVE this time.

Comment: I don’t understand, the problem is the same. How can I save the field in the second screen?